# Entity Framework Code First Fluent API configuration for one to one identifying relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, code-first, ef-fluent-api

I have the following class structure:

[image]

How to configure Fluent API to put identifying relationship in Cards table?

I mean

- Cards Table PK: Id, CustomerId
- Cards Table FK: CustomerId

I would like the previous Card be deleted when I assign a new one to Customer.Card property.

So I defined my classes this way:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual Card Card { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Card
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
}

public class Visa : Card
{
}

public class Amex : Card
{
}
```

DbContext looks like this:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Card> Cards { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .HasRequired(c => c.Card)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal()
            .Map(a => a.MapKey("CustomerId"))
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Card>();
    }
}
```

Here is the test:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var context = new Context();
        var customer = new Customer();
        context.Customers.Add(customer);
        customer.Card = new Visa();
        context.SaveChanges();

        customer.Card = new Amex();
        context.SaveChanges();

        Assert.AreEqual(1, context.Customers.Count());
        Assert.AreEqual(1, context.Cards.Count());
    }
}
```

It does not work at all. I have this on second save and I do not know how to specify identifying relationship here:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An err or
>   occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key
>   properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will
>   return null because a singl e entity cannot be identified as the
>   source of the exception. Handling of except ions while saving can be
>   made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types.
>   See the InnerException for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.U
>   pdateException: A relationship from the 'Customer_Card' AssociationSet
>   is in the  'Deleted' state. Given multiplicity constraints, a
>   corresponding 'Customer_Card
>   _Target' must also in the 'Deleted' state.

**UPDATE** It's easy to make it work for one-to-many relationships. You can find a full example below:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var context = new Context();
        var customer = new Customer();
        context.Customers.Add(customer);
        customer.Cards.Add(new Visa());
        context.SaveChanges();

        customer.Cards[0] = new Amex();
        context.SaveChanges();

        Assert.AreEqual(1, context.Cards.Count());
    }
}

public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        Cards = new List<Card>();
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual List<Card> Cards { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Card
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; private set; }
}

public class Visa : Card
{
}

public class Amex : Card
{
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    static Context()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Context>());
    }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Card> Cards { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Cards)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.CustomerId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Card>()
            .HasKey(c => new { c.Id, c.CustomerId });
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem may be with your unit test: `context.Customers.Add(new Customer());` does not add the same object as `var customer = new Customer();`

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question. I still don't know how to specify identifying relationship here...

Comment: I guess you miss CustomerId in your Card class

Comment: Could you please show how do you see it? I tried it already...

Comment: `public abstract class Card
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
}` looks missing `CustomerId`

Comment: I would really appreciate if you make this test work. To get rid of orphans we need identifying relationship and it's not clear how to do it here.

Comment: `modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().WillCascadeOnDelete()         .HasRequired(c => c.Card).WithRequiredDependent().Map(a => a.MapKey("CustomerId"))`;

Comment: It will basically places CustomerId FK in Customers table, which is useless.

Comment: so just swap that: `modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().WillCascadeOnDelete().HasRequired(c => c.Card).Map(a => a.MapKey("CustomerId")).WithRequiredDependent();`

Comment: Please try it first yourself. :(

Comment: sorry about that because I don't have VS on my PC now

Comment: Customer is a principal here as far as I can understand. Could you please come with some code in a dedicated answer below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way EF implements one-to-one is to make the dependent entity have a primary key that's also a foreign key to the principle entity. So the dependent's PK is naturally constrained to existing principle PK values.

So using your classes, slightly modified:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; private set; }
    public virtual Card Card { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Card
{
    public int CustomerId { get; private set; }
}

public class Visa : Card { }

public class Amex : Card { }
```

And the mapping:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasRequired(c => c.Card)
                                   .WithRequiredPrincipal();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Card>().HasKey(c => c.CustomerId);
}
```

So `Card` only has `CustomerId` as PK *and* FK, not two separate fields.

**BUT**

Trying this, I found out that there's a bug in EF (6.1.2). This is what I did:

```
using (var db = new TempModelsContext())
{
    var cst = new Customer { Name = "Customer1", 
                             Card = new Amex { Number = "Amex" } };
    db.Customers.Add(cst);
    db.SaveChanges();
}

using (var db = new TempModelsContext())
{
    var cst = db.Customers.Include(c => c.Card).Single(c => c.CustomerId == 1);
    cst.Card = new Visa { Number = "Visa" };
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

(Added `Name` and `Number` for convenience).

Normally this would be OK. EF is smart enough to see that a 1:1 dependent entity is replaced and it just *updates* the `Number` field (effectively deleting the old card).

But **EF overlooks the inheritance** (for which I used the default, TPH). Of course it should also update the discriminator field, but it doesn't. You end up with an `Amex` card, having "Visa" as number if you re-fetch the items from the database.

So, sadly, even with this model, you first have to remove the old card, and then add the new one:

```
var cst = db.Customers.Include(c => c.Card).Single(c => c.CustomerId == 1);
db.Cards.Remove(cst.Card);
db.SaveChanges();

cst.Card = new Visa { Number = "Visa" };
db.SaveChanges();
```

This is clumsy enough, not to mention that you'd also want to wrap this in a `TransactionScope`.

Comment: No, TPT works when you use the same instance of DbContext. Another instance throws duplicate primary key exception on save...

Comment: You may consider not using inheritance. There are other patterns to program behavioral differences, e.g. Strategy. Inheritance with ORMs often causes more problems than its (lack of) necessity justifies. Performance can be hit badly, to mention another.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework doesn't really allow this sort of an operation.  You can't "delete" an object from the database simply by trying to replace it with another object.  even with Cascade Delete, you still have to issue a delete command in Entity Framework, else you end up with an orphaned item in your context.  You can *try* to override the `SaveChanges()` method to trap this behavior, but it won't be an easy patch.

your best bet would be to check if a card exists, and if so remove it before adding the new card.  this can easily be wrapped up into a repeatable function call, like so:

```
public void AddCard(Customer customer, Card card, Context context)
{
    if (customer.Card != null)
    {
        context.Cards.Remove(customer.Card);
    }
    customer.Card = card;
}
```

**Edit**

To be more clear, Entity Framework cannot batch a deletion of a relational object and the addition of a replacement object into the same `SaveChanges()` call.

This works fine:

```
Customer.Card = null;
SaveChanges();
Customer.Card = new Amex();
SaveChanges();
```

Note the multiple calls to `SaveChanges()`.  The function provided earlier is more a wrapper function to avoid the extra `SaveChanges()` call.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee373856%28v=vs.100%29.aspx  
Removing the relationship deletes the dependent object. Calling the Remove method on the EntityCollection marks both the relationship and the dependent object for deletion.

Comment: yes, but you aren't calling the `Remove()` method in your code sample.  if you assign the object to `null` it will be removed during the next `SaveChanges()` event. However, assigning the object to another object is an error, as it is still in the Deleted state until `SaveChanges()` synchronizes the objects.  Your error even validates this, saying that >A relationship is in the 'Deleted' state.

Comment: 1) It throws on after null assignment save for me. 2) I actually do not have an identifying relationship here as I don't know how to configure it in this situation so there is no much to expect anyway.